# Laravel relationship always returning empty array

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel, orm, relationship

I have two models in a Laravel application `Ft` and `Fi`.

`Ft` contains the following code:

```php
protected $table = 'ft';

protected $connection = 'XXX';

protected $keyType = 'string';

public function lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fi', 'ftstamp', 'ftstamp');
}
```

`Fi` contains the following code:

```php
protected $table = 'fi';
```

In my controller I have the following code

```php
Ft::select($fields)->with(['lines'])
```

All results have `"lines": []`

Relationship exists in database.

Database is SQL Server

`ft.ftstamp` and `fi.ftstamp` field is type `char`.

Driver used for connection is `sqlsrv`.

Comment: Have you tried `Ft::select($fields)->with(['lines'])->toSql()` to see what query it is trying to run?

Comment: @JustCarty This return "select [ftstamp], [fno], [no], [ftano], [fdata], [nome], [pdata], [etotal], [nmdoc] from [ft]"

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it. If you only select certain fields from the table, ensure that the primary key is one of them. The eager load is done as a separate query, not a join, so the key values have to be available.

For example, this code:

```php
User::select(["id", "name"])->with("posts")->get();
```

Runs two database queries:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM users;
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?...);
```

The second query is populated with the `id` values from the first. Without those values, the second query can't be run.

In a normal database, this would mean making sure that the array `$fields` contains "id" as an element, and I'd provide a code sample. Your database looks frightening however, so I won't try.

Comment: I made a listener to log all querys.
The second query appear in the logs.
select * from [fi] where [fi].[ftstamp] in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

But the result set is:
[ { "ftstamp": "ADM15071434897,392995282", "fno": 1, "no": 3, "ftano": 2015, "fdata": "2015-07-14 00:00:00.000", "nome": "Santa Casa da Misericórdia de Lagos", "pdata": "2015-07-29 00:00:00.000", "etotal": "466.120000", "nmdoc": "Fatura", "lines": [] }, ... ]